# How to force 9 patch images to scale only for Views that require more space in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, nine-patch

I have a `RecyclerView` which I update with message, I've set the background to the `Textview` inside the `RecyclerView` with a `9-patch-image` .

Now, the **problem** is that : When the length of the message is small, the 9 patch images are working well, and are scaling only to the size of the space the text occupies, but when one message consist a text with many characters, obviously the 9 patch image scales, but when it does it also scales all the previous elements in the `RecyclerView`.

What is possibly causing this and how to fix it?

Here is the code to my adapter:

**CustomAdapter.class**

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.FeedsViewHolder>
{



    DataHolder d1 = new DataHolder();

    public  class FeedsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView chat;
        private Typeface face;
        private Context mcontext;

        FeedsViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mcontext = itemView.getContext();
            chat = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
            face = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            chat.setTypeface(face);


        }



    }

    private static class DataHolder
    {
        List<Text> feeds;

    }



    CustomAdapter(List<Text> feeds)
    {
        this.d1.feeds = feeds;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    @Override
    public FeedsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_message, viewGroup, false);
        FeedsViewHolder pvh = new FeedsViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedsViewHolder feedViewHolder, int i)
    {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)feedViewHolder.chat.getLayoutParams();
        feedViewHolder.chat.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        if(d1.feeds.get(i).isMachineOrHuman())
        {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            feedViewHolder.chat.setLayoutParams(params);
            feedViewHolder.chat.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(feedViewHolder.mcontext, R.drawable.user));
            feedViewHolder.chat.setText(d1.feeds.get(i).getMessage());
        }

        else
        {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
            feedViewHolder.chat.setLayoutParams(params);
            feedViewHolder.chat.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(feedViewHolder.mcontext, R.drawable.ais));
            feedViewHolder.chat.setText(d1.feeds.get(i).getMessage());
        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {

        if(d1.feeds!=null)
        {
            return d1.feeds.size();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }



}
```

This is where the background is set:

```
    feedViewHolder.chat.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(feedViewHolder.mcontext, R.drawable.user));
feedViewHolder.chat.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(feedViewHolder.mcontext, R.drawable.ais));
```

This is the `XML` to the adapter's `TextView`:

**chat_message.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/chat_rel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/chatMessage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:gravity="start"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**EDIT-1**

This is how it looks before and after:

`IMAGE-1`

[image]

`IMAGE-2`

[image]

Comment: It's probably because of the attribute `android:gravity="start"`. you have to change the gravity at runtime for both of the chats. The right one should have `android:gravity="end"`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, can you elaborate it more?

Comment: That fixed the issue, post it as an answer, may help someone in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly, the issue was where I defined the gravity:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/chat_rel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/chatMessage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:gravity="start" <!-- here -->
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**The solution:**

Removed `android:gravity="start"` from the XML and defined it programatically:

```
            feedViewHolder.chat.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            feedViewHolder.chat.setGravity(Gravity.END);
```

The `onBindViewHolder()` becomes:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedsViewHolder feedViewHolder, int i)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)feedViewHolder.chat.getLayoutParams();

    if(d1.feeds.get(i).isMachineOrHuman())
    {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        feedViewHolder.chat.setLayoutParams(params);
        feedViewHolder.chat.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        feedViewHolder.chat.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(feedViewHolder.mcontext, R.drawable.user));
        feedViewHolder.chat.setText(d1.feeds.get(i).getMessage());
    }

    else
    {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        feedViewHolder.chat.setLayoutParams(params);
        feedViewHolder.chat.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        feedViewHolder.chat.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(feedViewHolder.mcontext, R.drawable.ais));
        feedViewHolder.chat.setText(d1.feeds.get(i).getMessage());
    }



}
```